# Rsync don't copy .BAK files

Tags: rsync

I'm using **rsync** to backup some files, but I realized that files with a .bak extension are not being copied.

`sudo rsync -Cravp --delete /home/administrador/ArquivosAL/ /media/administrador/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/Backup`

Some one knows why? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `-C` option with `rsync` then it initializes an exclude list which contains `.BAK` files along with many others.
You can use `man rsync` and look at what all is excluded by the `-C` option.

If you want to copy the `.BAK` files remove the above mentioned option from your command. Although, **Note that** this will mean that anything which was previously excluded due to this option will also be copied.

Thus your new command would be :

`sudo rsync -ravp --delete /home/administrador/ArquivosAL/ /media/administrador/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/Backup`